# Interesting question on Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Ran across this interesting question about the Fibonacci numbers but quite unsure how to go about it, any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: For instance, the idea that comes  after the word "*Hint:*"

Answer (score 2):

hint for second part$$f_{n+1}=f_n+f_{n-1}\\f_{n}=f_n+0\\\to\\$$
$$f_{n+1}=f_n+f_{n-1}\\f_{n}=f_n+0f_{n-1}$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}f_{n+1}\\ f_{n}\end{array}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\c & d \end{bmatrix}.\left(\begin{array}{c}f_{n}\\ f_{n-1}\end{array}\right)\\\left(\begin{array}{c}f_{n+1}\\ f_{n}\end{array}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.\left(\begin{array}{c}f_{n}\\ f_{n-1}\end{array}\right)$$